# Sed oneliner to get filename and containing directory

Tags: path, regex, sed

I need to extract the filename and containing directory from a full path (DOS syntax).  I need to do this using sed as it is part of a larger regular expression.

Example input: ..\home\test\somedir\anotherdir\myfile.txt

Expected output: anotherdir\myfile.txt

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just go at it methodically. You want to divide a line into three parts: an arbitrary prefix `.*`, and then twice a backslash followed by non-backslash characters `\\[^\\]*`. Capture what's after the next-to-last backslash and drop the rest.

```
printf %s "$dos_path" | sed 's/^.*\\\([^\\]*\\[^\\]*\)$/\1/'
```

(Beware of `echo` as some shells expand backslashes.)

Comment: Awesome works a treat, thanks. Yeah I probably could have got there on my own but my mind had turned to mush yesterday after reading and writing regular expressions all day!

Answer (score 0):

Is there a particular reason to not use awk?

```
echo $DIR | awk -F'\' '{ print $(NF-1) "\\" $NF }'
```

Comment: As I said in my question, it is part of a larger regular expression that I already have.  I would have had to rewrite the rest of the regular expression in awk syntax in order to fit this in.  Plus my awk knowledge is more-or-less non-existent unfortunately.